# Previously None-Existent Files that I am Opening Aren't Showing Up. Python - REPL.it

Tags: python, file, saving-data, replit

I am opening a new file (which didn't exist until now) using this line of code:

```
file_number = input("What number player are you? ")
with open(os.path.join(playergold, "gold.%s.txt" % file_number), "w") as g:

#playergold is the directory 'PlayerFiles/PlayerItems'
```

The computer can use the files once, but not read the files, or write in them afterwards, and I cannot find them anywhere in the file view screen. Even after the program successfully ends, they are none-existent. Is this something **repl.it** does, or are they loading wrong, or something else I don't know? Please help! Anything at all is helpful!

This is what my screen looks like: [image]

On the left, if you enter in a new number, a new file is supposed to be put inside the PlayerGold folder. (The other error I am currently experiencing is not a part of the question.)

Comment: Try to open file in `binary` mode for witing and write binary or Unicode string to tackle `io.UnsupportedOperation`

Comment: Nvm, I forgot to change the mode from `"w"` to `"r"` when reading. Looks like it _is_ possible to create the file, write to it and then read from it, but it doesn't show up in the file browser anyway...

Comment: @Sampath , my writing code was just wrong. It said `'r'` instead of `'w'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Let me try to answer this,

1. You are opening a new file in `write` mode. So basically, you are creating it. This is similar to opening a VI editor. You can open VI, write something and close it without saving it!
2. Since you are using both context manager and saving file pointer as `g`, try to print it. Here is one example of expected output for `g`

```
>>> fp = open('/tmp/sam123', 'w')
>>> fp
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/sam123' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

3. (Optional) If possible try to segregate your code to do a `os.path.join` and `open` in two different steps. This helps in debugging.

Comment: How do I permanently make a file with code then? Because that is the objective.

Comment: Also, why would I want to print it?

Comment: @FrasherGray - I am not completely sure of how/what went wrong at your end, so I had only some potentials guesswork solutions. So is why print. If you have successfully come out f context manager('with'), your file should be created by then.

Comment: Oh I see, @Sampath. If it prints, it exists, it it doesn't, something when wrong?

Comment: I am going to try downloading the files and running it on my computer. Because I ran the code on repl.it and it printed the correct directories and file, but it still didn't show up.